# vendor.ts to vendor.js compiling fails

Tags: javascript, typescript, vendor

**Stack**

Hi, I am bootstrapping a MEAN stack application. We are using Angular2 and typescript. Gulp is used for the build. I develop on a MAC OS machine.

**Issue**

When I run my application locally as always with `gulp watch` and open `localhost:3000` my Angular application does not load and I have in my JavaScript Console the following error :

[image]

When I google this issue, I found these articles :

- [Angular2 + Jspm.io : reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911861/angular2-jspm-io-reflect-metadata-shim-is-required-when-using-class-decorato)
- https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/353

Seem they both advice to add 2 supposed missing imports :

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

But I have in my `vendor.ts` file already these two imports :

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

After running `gulp watch` I have the following content in my transpiled `vendor.js` file

```
"use strict";
require('shim');
require('rxjs/add/operator/map');
require('validate.js');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('reflect-metadata');
require('@angular/core');
require('@angular/common');
require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic');
require('@angular/router-deprecated');
require('@angular/http');
```

But when I compare this `vendor.js` file with my friend who runs `gulp watch` on a (windows) machine, they are very different. His `vendor.js` file has way more generated code in that file. (2000+ lines). When I copy the content of his `vendor.js` file into my `vendor.js` file, the solution works locally. But obviously after every build, the content will be regenerated and cause the same issue.

**Solutions**

I have tried to run `typings install` , `npm install` and `npm cache clear` already a few times but I fail to get the solution running locally. I have no pending local changes, neither does my friend who is able to run it.

**So has anyone an idea in what I have to look into to figure out why the `vendor.js` is not well generated ?**

Thank you for your time

**EDIT 1**

As requested my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Funny fact : When I am watching my solution with `gulp watch` and I edit my `vendor.ts` with a simple new line for example, and I refresh my page after the watch picked up the change, everything works. But when I stop my watch en run again `gulp watch` I face the same issue again.

Comment: can you post your tsconfig? are you using the following options? 
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,

Comment: Have you got require.js installed?

Comment: @tadwork : Added, I do not have `"noEmitHelpers": false` , I tried it, but didn't help

Comment: @WayneRiesterer : I don't have that installed, I use webpack, by loading my `vendor.js` it should define the function `require()` no ?

Comment: Funny fact : When I am watching my solution with `gulp watch` and I edit my `vendor.ts` with a simple new line for example, and I refresh my page, everything works. But when I stop my watch en run again `gulp watch` I face the same issue again.

Comment: @IanS: I haven't used Webpack, but don't you have to install requirejs in order to use the require() function in your vendor.js file?

Comment: @WayneRiesterer : Well when I change my vendor.ts when my watch is on, it suddenly works, so I presume that the requirejs is not required and that there is a step being skipped on startup which does happen during my watch changes

Comment: @WayneRiesterer : I forgot to mention, I tried once with adding the RequireJS as you suggested, but then I don't have any issues with the 'require' keyword, but then I still get the error that he can't find that dependency that I am asking with the `require('myDependency')`