# Angular2 using either npm reflect-metadata or core-js/es7/reflect

Tags: javascript, angular, reflection, decorator

Looking at Angular2 projects, I see some are using:
npm reflect-metadata

and others are using :
core-js/es7/reflect

I know both are implementing the ES7 proposed Decorator and reflect API

But what is the difference between the two?
Are they just copy/paste ? 
I assume they are equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`core-js/es7/reflect:` The native JavaScript support for a [metadata reflection API](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/es7/reflect.js).

`npm reflect-metadata:` The TypeScript support for the [prototype of the ES7 Reflection API](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators/blob/master/spec/metadata.md).

Hope this help!

Comment: Can you answer the question directly in your SO answer? i.e. the first link is broken and it is still unclear to me, if they are the same or not.