# Correct way to reference reflect-metadata or equivalent in angular app

Tags: angular, reflection, reflect-metadata

In this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ikp7DV) I'm attempting to decorate a property on MyModel with a custom annotation. Un-commenting the property with custom decorator or un-commenting `import 'reflect-metadata';` and the property with inline decorator generates:

```
Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Parser'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Parser' is decorated with Injectable. at NoAnnotationError.ZoneAwareError
```

I can un-comment just the inline decorator but in an editor without the `import 'reflect-metadata';` you don't get code autocomplete and tsc error about metadata() not being a property of Reflect.

What is the correct way to use the reflect API in angular?

Edit:
With a new @angular/cli genrated app you have `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` in `pollyfills.ts` but you still get `Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.` if you try any combination of Reflect.metadata()

Edit2:
I seemingly have this working in angular cli by replacing `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` with `import 'reflect-metadata';` in `pollyfills.ts` but I don't know if they are one for one replacements or if there is ramifications. The answer here isn't clear to me. [Angular2 using either npm reflect-metadata or core-js/es7/reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607897/angular2-using-either-npm-reflect-metadata-or-core-js-es7-reflect)

Comment: I just ran into this error and you're the only I've found that has had it so far. I don't need to import anything for it to work, but of course tsc complains that `defineMetadata` doesn't exist on `Reflect`. I'm at a loss

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon [this article](http://myrighttocode.org/blog/typescript/angular2/decorators/angular2-custom-decorators) which might help.
I guess the part where "Second Problem" is addressed might be interesting to you. I faced the same problem trying to define some metadata in an angular application and it seems that angular is providing a different Reflect than window does. So accessing windows' reflect seems to fix the issue for me. I used:

```
let reflect = window['Reflect'];
reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, metadataValue, target);
```

instead of

```
Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, metadataValue, target);
```